# gut feelings in questions that may not have a clear answer

Tags: discussion

I just asked [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103925/should-i-use-a-subquery-to-help-sql-server-find-the-correct-plan) which may or may not have a clear answer, so at the end, I asked for "gut feelings" (or code smells, if that term translates to the database crowd), and then asked users to not down vote answers that are clearly marked as just a feeling without a complete explanation as to why it feels like a good or bad idea.

Is this acceptable?  I'm sort of used to non-database code where things are more black and white, but it seems like when I get into plan optimization, that this is as much art as science, and gut feelings are important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have a vote-to-close reason of "primarily opinion based."  There is no place for opinion here - we strictly go for reproducible answers to canonical questions.  "code smells" as you put it are not subjective; they result from experience with predictably bad outcomes arising from specific anti-patterns.  SQL Server has it's fair share of these, such as `WHERE BETWEEN date1 AND date2` - it's valid syntactically, but probably shouldn't be used unless you understand exactly all the pitfalls and problems it entails.

Comment: That's a great answer.  I will be editing my question shortly based on comments, so I will remove that bit when I do.  Thanks for the clarification.